# Change element of a modal once loaded - WP JS jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a modal that is loaded by clicking on a link. It shows the information for a particular course. So far everything is fine and working.

However, after this modal is already loaded and showing the values, I want to change the title text for example (h2). If I execute the change code via console everything works correctly, but not automatically. I understand that it must be a loading order issue or something like that. I've tried all the options below without success. Any suggestion?

```js
/* TESTE 1 */
jQuery(document).on('click', '.mec-monthly-tooltip', function() {
  jQuery("h1.mec-single-title").html('Novo Titulo');
  alert('Teste 1');
});


/* TESTE 2 */
jQuery('.mec-calendar-day h4.mec-event-title').bind('click', function(e) {
  $(this).one("ajaxStop", function() {
    jQuery("h1.mec-single-title").html('Novo Titulo');
    alert('Teste 2');
  });
});

/* TESTE 3 */
jQuery(document).on('click', '.mec-monthly-tooltip', function() {
  jQuery("h1.mec-single-title").html('Novo Titulo');
  alert('Teste 3');
});

/* TESTE 4 */
jQuery('h1.mec-single-title').bind('load', function() {
  jQuery("h1.mec-single-title").html('Novo Titulo');
  alert('Teste 4');
});

/* TESTE 5 */
jQuery(window).load(function() {
  jQuery("h1.mec-single-title").html('Novo Titulo');
  alert('Teste 5');
});
```

Comment: We need to see a working example of the code which displays the modal. Seeing the code which doesn't work isn't very helpful.

Comment: Just in case this is a silly mistake ... Your text description talks about "h2", but all of your selectors are looking for "h1".

Comment: TEST5 looks correct, but it's better that you use `.text()` instead of `.html()`. `jQuery("h1.mec-single-title").text('Novo Titulo');`

Comment: unfortunately I do not have access to the code that generates the modal, it is a wordpress plugin.
About H2 was just an example. I am using the correct element. As I said, I run the code on the browser console and it works.

Comment: On this page you have the calendar (click on the December event) to view the modal.

https://www.groupsd.pt/sentidos-dinamicos/formacao/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I couldn't get any solution via JS or Jquery, a colleague gave the tip to hide via CSS the first 4 elements and it worked.

```
body h4.mec-event-title {
    text-indent: -32px;
}
```